# SSIS package path - determining during execution

Tags: ssis, package

Using a SQL Server Agent job to start a SQL Server Integration Services Pachage step.....

In the package itself, is there a way to pick the path of the package that was started?

I want to pick up the "folder" info of where the package resided that is executing, to help build some variables.

TIA,

Doug

Comment: basically you need a table for storing the parameters like this

Comment: So "Run package C:\bar\blee\Foo.dtsx" and the question is, can the ssis package "know" it's on the file system at bar\blee?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me .
Viewing the List of Running Packages
You can view the list of packages that are currently running on the server in the Active Operations dialog box. For more information, see Active Operations Dialog Box.

For information about the other methods that you can use to view the list of running packages, see the following topics.

Transact-SQL access
To view the list of packages that are running on the server, query the view, catalog. executions (SSISDB Database) for packages that have a status of 2.

Programmatic access through the managed API
See the N: Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices namespace and its classes.

Use the Active Operations dialog box to view the status of currently running Integration Services operations on the Integration Services server, such as deployment, validation, and package execution. This data is stored in the SSISDB catalog.

**Open the Active Operations Dialog Box**

1. Open SQL ServerManagement Studio.
2. Connect Microsoft SQL Server Database Engine In Object Explorer,
3. expand the Integration Services node, right-click SSISDB, and then click Active Operations.
   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213131(v=sql.120).aspx